# Multiple file uploading php with variable

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have some issues trying to upload multiple files from the same page in PHP.

This is my set up:

```
<input type='file' name='file1'></input>
<input type='file' name='file2'></input>
<input type='file' name='file3'></input>
<input type='file' name='file4'></input>
```

What i need is the fileX for my sql query so i can connect it to that input.

Ive tried looping in this case

```
for(x=1, x<=4, x++){
   if($_FILES['file'.x][error] == 0){
       upload 
   }
}
```

when i upload one file the loop ends ?

Anyone ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the code of "upload" and how does your complete form look like?

Comment: And do a var_dump($_FILES) and post the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!empty($_FILES) {
    foreach($_FILES as $value)  
           // stuff to upload 
           // stuff to save in db
       }
    }
}
```

Links

- http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

Comment: Okey , cant really get my head around it but ill try. Looks like something im after ! Thanks

Comment: You can use methods like `print_r()`, `var_dump()` to track values you receive at any step, debug your code. Don't forget to put a `die()` after these methods if you want to stop your script execution and see what you are receiving actually.

Answer (score 0):

Just put [] at the end of the names.
Like

```
<input type='file' name='file[]'></input>
```

Multiple array file[][your_id];

Comment: Yeah i know, but what if my file_id(x) starts is 8 - 12,
    <input type='file' name='file8'></input>
    <input type='file' name='file9'></input>...

Then i use the file_id for query.

Comment: I want to use the number in "file1-X" as variable in insert to sql db

Comment: Then use multiple array file[][your_id]